# Javascript : Insane boolean test with '!' operator

Tags: javascript, regex, boolean

On inputting the following function call into chrome console:

```
(function(regex, str){
    console.log(regex.test(str))
    console.log(!regex.test(str))
    console.log(! regex.test(str))
    console.log( !regex.test(str))
    console.log( ! regex.test(str))
})(new RegExp("new", "gmi"), "new")
```

I get the following results:

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

Can someone explain why the 3rd and 5th tests return `false`?
And why the First and Second both return true.

Comment: more confusing is how the first two are providing the same result

Comment: @DLeh I am pulling my hair out. It is practically impossible to replicate this result any other way also.

Comment: @JoeButler if you take out the "g" modifier, it won't be strange anymore.

Comment: yeah i ran it as `...})(/new/, "new")` and it return `true` once and the rest `false`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're including the "g" modifier, so the regular expression object is maintaining the state of the match progress. Each call is not the same, in other words.

Your first call matches the string `"new"`, and the regex updates the position to the end of the string. The next match fails (so you see `true` for `!regexp.test(str)`). It fails because the string "new" does not appear at the end of the string "new".

Now we've run off the end of the string, so the next test starts over like the first. It matches again, so your `!` turns that `true` to `false`. The one after that doesn't match, and the one after *that* will have started over again and it matches.

Note that the spaces around `!` in the tests have absolutely nothing to do with the behavior.

*edit* — try this variation:

```
(function(regex, str){
    console.log(regex.test(str) + " - " + regex.lastIndex)
    console.log(!regex.test(str) + " - " + regex.lastIndex)
    console.log(! regex.test(str) + " - " + regex.lastIndex)
    console.log( !regex.test(str) + " - " + regex.lastIndex)
    console.log( ! regex.test(str) + " - " + regex.lastIndex)
})(new RegExp("new", "gmi"), "new")
```

You'll see that the `.lastIndex` property toggles between `0` and `3`.

I think that the moral of this story is "don't use `'g'` unless you really know you want to."

Comment: Thankyou, I can apparently accept this answer in 6 mins. I now realise I do not understand the 'g' modifier and its role within confusingly non independent regular expression tests.

Comment: @JoeButler see my update - the regexp object exposes a ".lastIndex" property that tells you where in the search string it will start the next search. You can explicitly set that back to zero if you want, or else just not use the "g" flag.

Comment: Yes I wont be using 'g' modifier, 'global' to me seems rather unintuitive for its function.

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain you what's happening. Go through the comments. Its in the form of

```
regex.lastIndex, actual value, negated value

// code below

(function(regex, str){
    console.log(regex.test(str)) // 0, true, false
    console.log(!regex.test(str)) // 3, false, true => lastIndex set to 0
    console.log(! regex.test(str)) // 0, true, false
    console.log( !regex.test(str)) // 3, false, true => lastIndex set to 0
    console.log( ! regex.test(str)) // 0, true, false
})(new RegExp("new", "gmi"), "new")
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

> If lastIndex is equal to the length of the string and if the regular
>   expression does not match the empty string, then the regular
>   expression mismatches input, and lastIndex is reset to 0.

So, `lastIndex` is updated in case a global regex is used more than once and it decides where to start matching.